# Error Connecting to Tor

Tags: tails, connection

Just recently installed Tails onto a USB, the first time I booted it up it seemed to connect fine. But then I restarted it and it's not working. I tried also on another laptop but still not working. Does anyone know how to fix this.

Comment: Can you post details? Is there an error message? Have you tried re-creating the Tails USB?

Comment: Yeah I tried reinstalling tails on the USB and it still doesn't work. It just says error connecting to Tor, and bring up the private bridges and proxy page.